# Torch / Lua, how to save a trained neural network model to file?

Tags: lua, parallel-processing, torch

I working on a Torch / Lua project, in which I implemented an artificial neural network model.
Everything works, but now I'd like to modify my code in the following way. Since my input dataset are very large, I'd like to divide it in N=20 spans.

Then I want to train my neural network only on the 1st dataset span and then test on the other N-1=19 spans in parallel.

To run all these parallel jobs, I need to save up my neural network model details to a file, and then load it for every 19 jobs.

**Is there any way in torch to correctly "write" an artificial neural network model to file?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
-- save the model
torch.save(filename, model)
```

.

```
-- load the model
model = torch.load(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks @smhx, easier than I thought!

Comment: Is there a way to save it and load it into Lua (without Torch)?

Comment: @Adam12344 before loading the network back into torch, you need to `require` the packages used in the serialized model, such as `nn`, otherwise the loading will fail. Consequently, this will certainly also fail with 'Lua (without Torch)' if you can't load e.g. the `nn` package before loading the model.