# Torch / Lua, why does my neural network model loaded from file not predict any negative elements?

Tags: lua, neural-network, training-data, torch

I've been working on an artificial neural network model in Torch / Lua, able to learn how to recognize true couples (ones) and false couples (zeros) of elements for a particular biological project.

The algorithm behaves this way: after the optimization phase in which the software select the best combination of hyper-parameters for the neural network, it runs a training phase, in which the software trains the neural network with the selected combination of best hyper-parameters, and finally saves the trained model to a file ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288006/torch-lua-how-to-save-a-trained-neural-network-model-to-file)). During the training, the model predicts both true couples and false couples.

Everything works so far...

Afterwards, in the testing phase, my software loads the model previously saved to a file, and applies it to new datasets.
Here go the problems: **during testing, the neural network surprisingly predicts only ones ("yes" couples) and never predicts any zeros ("false" couples).**

I've been working on this problem for weeks and I'm really not able to understand why this happens... **the neural network model correctly predicts ones and zeros during training, so why does it not predict any zeros during testing?**
Perhaps something unexplained happens in the model saving.

Any idea about what's happening?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you run the tests using your original training data, rather than new test data - still giving wrong results? If the training data works, but your test data doesn't you could be suffering from overfitting...

Comment: The data were very imbalanced, and this caused overfitting. The model was actually working correctly.

Comment: @JohnWakefield Could you please take a look to this question? http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/why-is-my-artificial-neural-networks-almost-always-predicting-positive-elements Thanks